# how to plot in different colors here according to x values?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

I need different color for all different x values. My x axis is having categorical data while y axis is having integers.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = pd.read_csv('Nissin_sy_1.csv')

x = df1['ptno']

y = df1['d']//1000000000

colors = np.where(df1["ptno"]== 'U','r','o')
colors[df1["ptno"]== '1234'] = 'g'
colors[df1["ptno"]== 'X32133301000'] = 'brown'
colors[df1["ptno"]== 'T7943000501'] = 'blue'
colors[df1["ptno"]== 'Z1900139901'] = 'yellow'
colors[df1["ptno"]== 'T7953000503'] = 'pink'
colors[df1["ptno"]== 'L1104105004'] = 'blue'
colors[df1["ptno"]== '-1'] = 'blue'
colors[df1["ptno"]== 'Z1672502003'] = 'black'    
colors[df1["ptno"]== 'T7953000505'] = 'cyan'
colors[df1["ptno"]== 'Y2323005900'] = 'white'
colors[df1["ptno"]== 'Z12129940400'] = 'gray'

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
fig.tight_layout() 
plt.scatter(x,y, s = 35 , c =colors )
plt.title("Cycling Duration v. Part_Name")
plt.xlabel("Part_Name")
plt.xticks(x, rotation= 'vertical')
plt.ylabel("Cycling Duration")
plt.ylim(0,93209)
plt.show()
```

But I get the plot only with blue colors.

How to get separate colors for separate x values. I am on python 2.7

[image: blue_color_for_all_x_values]

Comment: I tried your code and it's actually working for me. I replaced the reading from the file (which I didn't have) with this line- `df1=pd.DataFrame.from_dict ({'ptno': ['1234', 'X32133301000', 'T7943000501', 'Z1900139901', '1234', '-1'], 'd': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4]})`. Maybe try it and see if it working. I'm also using python 2.7, so I can't see a problem...

Comment: Hello @Shir your example is working correctly when I specify the colors , In my codes when I specify colors in `plt.scatter(x,y, s = 35 , c =colors )`  I am getting `ValueError: c of shape (530,) not acceptable as a color sequence for x with size 530, y with size 530 ` as error. Any idea to resolve this

Comment: Try to add `colors[df1["ptno"]== 'U'] = 'blue'` to the list, I think it is related to the fact that you don't have value in `colors` for each value. Does it working?

Comment: And maybe there are more values that are not written there, I didn't notice